# Ошибка Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

```
 private void topouts_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x;
        int.TryParse(topouts.Text, out x);
        if (x>0 & x<=16)
        {
            core.TopOuts = x;
            logbox.Text = $" core.TopOuts-> {topouts.Text.Length}";//не важно
        }
        else
        {  topouts.Text = topouts.Text.Remove(topouts.Text.Length-1);
            topouts.SelectionStart = topouts.Text.Length;
        }
```

В общем код должен проверять,что пользователь вводит 16<=число<0.
Но при вводе символа или если ввести символ и стереть его выводи ошибку что значение StartIndex не может быть меньше нуля(если что там специально затирается последний символ,что бы пользователь после 1 не мог 9 например ввести).Я понимаю почему выводит ошибку если ввести символ/число и стереть его,но почему при вводе просто символа(не числа) выводит ошибку, я не понимаю.Обьясните плиз) меня если что интересует только вышепоставленный вопрос так как возникновение других ошибок я понимаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ваша проблема тут:

```
topouts.Text.Remove(topouts.Text.Length-1)
```

для пустой строки `"".Length-1 == -1`, `Remove` принимает строго положительные индексы и 0.

Вторая проблема - событие `TextChanged` срабатывает после любого присваивания значения свойству `TextBox.Text`, а так как вы при предыдущем срабатывании удалили некорректный символ - на входе опять будет пустая строка. Т.е. фактически у вас получается косвенная рекурсия (присваивание - обработчик - присваивание - обработчик - ...), в результате символы будут удаляться до тех пор, пока значение не станет корректным, либо строка не кончится и произойдет исключение.

---

По поводу исправления, я бы советовал не затирать символы за пользователя, а только проверять корректность ввода. Если ввод некорректный - перекрасить цвет фона в красный например, чтобы пользователь видел введенное значение. Ну и подсказка всплывающая или просто `Label` под полем мелким шрифтом, о допустимых значениях. Почему именно так - ну хотя бы потому, что в этом случае не возникнет проблем при вставке значения из буфера обмена и не придется дополнительно обрабатывать и этот случай.

---

Ну ок, пусть будет тут:

```
private void topouts_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(topouts.Text))
    {
        this.topouts.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
        return;
    }
    int x;
    if(int.TryParse(topouts.Text, out x) && x >= 0 && x <= 16)
    {
        core.TopOuts = x;
        this.topouts.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.MenuHighlight;
        logbox.Text = $" core.TopOuts-> {core.TopOuts}";
    }
    else
    {
        this.topouts.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: но ведь когда мы вводим символ она не пустая,а ошибку выводит как раз в момент ввода символа

Comment: @Whitehorse а вы думаете, что после Remove событие не срабатывает повторно? Вы же меняете свойство

Comment: @Whitehorse дополнил

Comment: @Whitehorse Косвенная рекурсия (вспомнил как называется=)), последовательные вызовы при каждом присваивании значения.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void topouts_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x=17;
        if(topouts.Text.All(char.IsDigit)) { int.TryParse(topouts.Text, out x); }  
        if (topouts.Text.Length == 0) { this.topouts.BackColor = 
System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window; }
        if (x>=0 && x<=16 )
        {
            core.TopOuts = x;
            this.topouts.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.MenuHighlight;
            logbox.Text = $" core.TopOuts-> {core.TopOuts}";
        }
        else
        {
            this.topouts.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
```

В общем сделал чтоб подсвечивалось красным если ввод не корректный и синим если корректный,но при вводе числа больше 10000000000 фон опять становится синим...почему?

Comment: Ну это совсем просто. `TryParse` при неудаче возвращает дефолтное значение в out-переменную, для int - это 0, а он подходит под условие. Но лучше дополнительные вопросы задавать в отдельном вопросе, при необходимости добавив ссылку на первичный

Comment: Оформите ваш текущий ответ отдельным вопросом, напишу как исправить ваш вариант. Это не моя вредность, просто тут так принято.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде так все нормально:

```
private void topouts_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        int x=17;
        if(topouts.Text.All(char.IsDigit)&& topouts.Text.Length<10) { 
int.TryParse(topouts.Text, out x); }  
        if (topouts.Text.Length == 0) { this.topouts.BackColor = 
System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window; }
        if (x>=0 && x<=16 )
        {
            core.TopOuts = x;
            this.topouts.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.MenuHighlight;
            logbox.Text = $" core.TopOuts-> {core.TopOuts}";
        }
        else
        {
            this.topouts.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
```

и очень хочется заменить 
    topouts.Text.Length <10
на 
    x.GetType().MaxValue.ToString().Lengh<10
я знаю,извращенство но можно как нибудь так?суть думаю поняли)

Comment: а нет не все нормально,теперь почему то при отсутствии символов форма не делает ее обратно белой System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window

Comment: слишком усложняете. Я дополнил ответ. И цвета по мягче выберите, слишком вырвиглазно получилось =)

Comment: все бы хорошо но все таки белый цвет не возвращается при отсутствии символов(по крайне мере перестал)

Comment: а точно ни чего не поменяли в моем варианте? я его как бы проверял перед публикацией. Да и всевозможные пробелы это тоже символы, так что если нет видимых значков - не значит что нет символов

Comment: при занулении объекта topouts.Text  все равно почему то синий.\\\прошу прощения,не заметил ваше решение)оно норм работает,но мне по прежнему интересно почему в моем не выводится белый XDD

Comment: Да тоже просто все. вы же после установки белого дальше проверяете на допустимость значений вместо завершения работы, а 0 допустимое значение

Comment: Ну и еще немного позанудствую: если под вашим вопросом есть ответ, который помог решить вашу проблему, отмечайте его галочкой, чтобы другие пользователи видели, что проблема решена.

Comment: но таки не 0,при пустой строке с переменной x ничего не должно произойти(TryParse не занулит)  \\\\я первый день на форуме)буду знать

Comment: абсолютно с вами согласен с TryParse но TryParse не будет выполняться пока это ложно: topouts.Text.All(char.IsDigit)

Comment: Именно что занулит, потому что All для пустого списка вернет true. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2 Метанит - это неплохо, но тонкости лучше читать в документации

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85601/discussion-between-rdorn-and-whitehorse).